# How can I share a powerpoint presentation on Lync SDK? (WPF application)

Tags: wpf, powerpoint, presentation, lync-2010, lync

I'm trying to find a way to share my presentation on my WPF application based on Lync SDK. But so far, I couldn't found a way.

`AutomationModailities` class only supports audio, video, text and file sharing. There are no Lync related buttons for sharing presentation on Toolbox neither.

What I want to achieve is this, programmatically on the codebehind. Like when user clicks on a button created dynamically on my WPF application it will do the same effect as this;

[image]

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is currently possible with the Lync SDK. As you dicovered yourself, there is no support for powerpoint sharing in AutomationModalities.

The other thing that makes me think the underlying API does not support this is that there are no Lync SDK UI controls that offer this functionality.

You could potentially do something by using a combination of Win32 calls and [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) to send keystrokes to the conversation window, to open the "Share/Powerpoint Presentation" menu option

Comment: Thanks again, when it comes to Lync I know I can count on you! I'm willing to do anything to make the job. My idea was the same actually, simulating mouseclicks or keystrokes but in a lot more amateur way (like clicking share tab and selecting file). Is there any way to ditch the open file dialog that needs me to select presentation file from hdd. Can I set it to C:\mypresentation.pptx or something? Thanks again!